# Why is there an amplitude difference in Matlab and Python?

Tags: matlab, python, amplitude

I've been trying to read an audio file in Matlab using this code --

`q = audioread('C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\cha1.wav');
figure; plot(q);`

Translated to Python, the code looks like this --

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

tup = scipy.io.wavfile.read("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/cha1.wav")
orig_sample_rate = tup[0]
q = tup[1]
```

When I try to plot these in Matlab, they produce the same waveform with different amplitudes.

Figure 1: Matlab code, Figure 2: Python code

How can I make the amplitudes the same? Scaling down did not produce accurate results.

[image: Matlab vs Python]

Comment: what's there to solve? Two different programs interpret the same file differently, but with a factor? That's not a problem, that's *just interpretation*.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear. I want to know how to make the amplitudes the same. Scaling down by a factor did not give accurate results.

Comment: "not accurate" in which way? What's the difference? (please try to give all relevant info)

Comment: Is it just that Matlab normalizes with a factor of $2^{15}$ or so?

Comment: How are you moving from Python to Matlab to plot the second signal ? There might be some spurious gain in the conversion

Comment: I used the function scipy.io.savemat(filename, mdict) in Python specifying the variables I want to use in mdict. I loaded the .mat file into matlab by using load, then used the plot() on the python variables that are now accessible from Matlab.

Comment: I suspect python is reading signed 16 bit int values from the wav file whereas Matlab is rescaling it to floating point numbers between [-1,1]. Try the "native" option with audioread in Matlab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html#inputarg_dataType

Comment: @AtulIngle Works beautifully. Turns out Matlab was the one scaling it differently. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect python is reading signed 16 bit int values from the wav file whereas Matlab is rescaling it to floating point numbers between [-1,1]. Try the "native" option with audioread in Matlab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html#inputarg_dataType

Answer (score 3):

This function of Matlab use an algorithm that normalized every data of an external medium, while Pyhton doesn't do that. You just need to multiply the Matlab values to `32,767.0` or divide Python values to the same value. That number is because you are using a file with each value has 16 bits, but with sign, so $$2^{16}/2 = 32767$$